# Paho-mqtt callbacks in different classes android java

Tags: java, android, callback, mqtt, paho

I've just started Java Android programming, or even Java programming in general and I wanted to implement the Paho MQTT Android Service using a certain MqttHandler class and I want to set the callback as a parameter for the MqttHandler class. Other answers regarding callbacks in general suggested using an interface class but I don't know how that works. This is what I have tried:

```
public interface InterfaceMqttCallback extends MqttCallbackExtended{
    @Override
    public void connectComplete(boolean b, String s);

    @Override
    public void connectionLost(Throwable throwable);

    @Override
    public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage mqttMessage) throws Exception ;

    @Override
    public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken iMqttDeliveryToken);

}
```

the MqttHandler class constructor:

```
public MqttHandler(Context context, InterfaceMqttCallback mqttCallbackExtended){
    mqttAndroidClient = new MqttAndroidClient(context, serverUri, clientId);
    mqttAndroidClient.setCallback(mqttCallbackExtended);
    connect();
}
```

a function in the Activity that initializes the MqttHandler:

```
private void startMqtt(){

    mqttHandler = new MqttHandler(getApplicationContext(), new InterfaceMqttCallback() {
        @Override
        public void connectComplete(boolean b, String s) {
            Log.w("Anjing", s);
        }

        @Override
        public void connectionLost(Throwable throwable) {

        }

        @Override
        public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage mqttMessage) throws Exception {
            Log.w("Anjing", mqttMessage.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken iMqttDeliveryToken) {

        }
    });

}
```

But as I've tested it, I think the callbacks was not set because none of the messages have been received. So then I tried setting the callbacks directly in the MqttHandler and it works, the messages are received.

```
public MqttHandler(Context context, InterfaceMqttCallback mqttCallbackExtended){
    mqttAndroidClient = new MqttAndroidClient(context, serverUri, clientId);
    mqttAndroidClient.setCallback(new InterfaceMqttCallback() {
        @Override
        public void connectComplete(boolean b, String s) {
            Log.w("mqtt", s);
        }

        @Override
        public void connectionLost(Throwable throwable) {

        }

        @Override
        public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage mqttMessage) throws Exception {
            Log.w("Anjing", mqttMessage.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken iMqttDeliveryToken) {

        }
    });
    connect();
}
```

So what's the problem? Thanks in advance..

EDIT: Of course I can set the `mqttAndroidClient` variable in the MqttHandler class as public, but is it safe?

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to set callback handler is setting it in MQTT client, like following:

```
        public class MTTConnector { 
            public void connect {
              MqttAndroidClient mqttClient = new MqttAndroidClient(BaseApplication.getAppContext(), broker, MQTT_CLIENT_ID); 
              mqttClient.setCallback(new MqttCallbackHandler(BaseApplication.getAppContext()));
          }
        }

    public class MqttCallbackHandler implements MqttCallbackExtended {
    @Override
        public void connectComplete(boolean b, String s) {
            Log.w("mqtt", s);
        }

        @Override
        public void connectionLost(Throwable throwable) {

        }

        @Override
        public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage mqttMessage) throws Exception {
            Log.w("Anjing", mqttMessage.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken iMqttDeliveryToken) {

        }
  }
```

If you are using latest version your call back need to implement MqttCallbackExtended class, see following link for more details on online GitHub project.

[MqttCallbackExtended.java](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.java/blob/master/org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3/src/main/java/org/eclipse/paho/client/mqttv3/MqttCallbackExtended.java)

Inside your activity initialize MTTConnector and call connect.

Hoping this help.

Cheers !

Comment: Yes, I am extending the MqttCallBackExtended class, but what I want to accomplish is to separate the Activity class and the Mqtt client class, where I can set the callback in the Activity class. This is so I can put all the Mqtt business in one class, except the callback, because I want to call a bunch of handler classes in the Activity class. I don't want to clutter the Activity class with a bunch of Mqtt.

Comment: Yes, you dont to, please see updated code. Inside your activity initialize MTTConnector and call connect.